# How to consolidate/divide rows within a data frame based on a value within a certain column using pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, list, dataframe

The starting df is as follows:

```
company  metric  time   data
x        X10384  M1     100
x        X10384  M2     100
x        X10384  M3     100
y        X10456  M4     200
y        X10456  M5     200
y        X10456  M6     200
```

I need to be able to consolidate these rows based on the value of the time dimension. Basically "M1, M2, M3" will encompass Q1 and "M4, M5, M6" will encompass Q2 and so on.

The resulting df will need to be as follows:

```
company  metric  time   data
x        X10384  Q1     300
y        X10456  Q2     600
```

Similarly, if starting with a df already in quarters, I will need to be able split the time into months and split the data into an equal three, like in the initial df.

How would one go about trying to transformation this data as above? The below is my starting point for reference:

```
quarters = ['Q1', 'Q2']
months = ['M1','M2','M3','M4','M5','M6']

for time in df['time']:
    if time in quarters:
        [insert transformation into individual months]
    elif time in months:
        [insert transformation into quarters]
```

Answer (score 0):

Extract digits from `time` column then convert them to quarter number. Finally, a simple `groupby_sum` do the job:

```
# Convert M1, M2, M3, M4, M5, M6 to Q1, Q1, Q1, Q2, Q2, Q2
to_quarter = df['time'].str[1:].astype(int).floordiv(4).add(1).astype(str).radd('Q')

out = df.assign(time=to_quarter).groupby(['company', 'metric', 'time']) \
                                .sum().reset_index()
```

Output:

```
>>> out
  company  metric time  data
0       x  X10384   Q1   300
1       y  X10456   Q2   600
```

Comment: For your other part (quarter to month) how to know which month?

Answer (score 0):

Creating a dataframe based on your data:

```
data = {'Company' : ['x', 'x', 'x', 'y', 'y', 'y'],  
        'Metric' : ['X10384', 'X10384', 'X10384', 'X10456', 'X10456', 'X10456'],
        'time': ['M1', 'M2', 'M3', 'M4', 'M5', 'M6'],
        'data': [100, 100, 100, 200, 200, 200]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

Then create a dictionary and map it per time:

```
dict = {'M1': 'Q1', 'M2' : 'Q1', 'M3' : "Q1", 'M4' : 'Q2', 'M5' : 'Q2', 'M6' : 'Q2'}
df['time'] = df['time'].map(dict)
```

And groupby will give you the final result:

```
df.groupby(['Company','Metric','time']).sum().reset_index()
```

Comment: +1 but you can pass `as_index=False` to `groupby` to not write `reset_index` at the end; but if you find `reset_index` more readable, that's also understandable IMHO. Also, shadowing the built-in `dict`, as the highlighter signals, renders it unusable afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

**From months to quarters**

input

```
company  metric  time   data
x        X10384  M1     100
x        X10384  M2     100
x        X10384  M3     100
y        X10456  M4     200
y        X10456  M5     200
y        X10456  M6     200
```

create a dictionary with a key in months for a value in quarters and map up column with key

```
months_to_quarters_dict = {'M1': 'Q1', 'M2' : 'Q1', 'M3' : "Q1", 'M4' : 'Q2', 'M5' : 'Q2', 'M6' : 'Q2'}
df['time'] = df['time'].map(months_to_quarters_dict)
```

output (1a)

```
company  metric  time   data
x        X10384  Q1     100
x        X10384  Q1     100
x        X10384  Q1     100
y        X10456  Q2     200
y        X10456  Q2     200
y        X10456  Q2     200
```

use a groupby().agg('sum') to get condensed df

```
df.groupby(['Company','Metric','time'], as_index=False).agg('sum')
```

output (1b)

```
company  metric  time   data
x        X10384  Q1     300
y        X10456  Q2     600
```

**From quarters to months**

input

```
company  metric  time   data
x        X10384  Q1     300
y        X10456  Q2     600
```

create a dictionary with a key in quarters for value in months and map up column with key

```
quarters_to_months_dict = {'Q1' : ['M1', 'M2', 'M3'], 'Q2' : ['M4', 'M5', 'M6']}
df['time'] = df['time'].map(months_to_quarters_dict)
```

output (2a)

```
  company  metric time  data
0       x  X10384   ['M1', 'M2', 'M3']   300
1       y  X10456   ['M4', 'M5', 'M6']   600
```

split rows using explode on time column and divide up data column by 3 to yield an equal amount for each month in a quarter

```
df = df.explode('time')
df['data'] = df['data].div(3)
```

output (2b)

```
company  metric  time   data
x        X10384  M1     100
x        X10384  M2     100
x        X10384  M3     100
y        X10456  M4     200
y        X10456  M5     200
y        X10456  M6     200
```